# SQL Server: Overflow of float data type during simple transfer operation

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a SSIS that copies data from one database to the other. The tables are created using identical script and contain a number of float columns with default precision.

Is it possible for an overflow error to occur while copying data because data in the source column (float) is larger than space available in target column (also float with same default precision)?

## **Update 1**

The error message that I am getting follows the details.

1. The SSIS succeeds about 90% of the time.
2. The data is being transferred across 2 different internal domains.
3. There are other tasks and databases on both source and destination servers.
4. The data being transferred is about a few million rows per run and variation in execution times are large, the maximum durations are sometimes three times as much as the minimum durations.
5. Schema is JDEdwards tables, we use the same source and target schema.
6. Timeout is 180 seconds.

We have been suggesting that this is an infrastructure issue but our support team insists that it is a data issue.

What might be the possible cause of this error and what would be the most appropriate course of further investigation. Performance counters?

> **Please comment if the error message suggests that this is a data issue.**

[image]

## **Update 2**

The destination is configured as follows.
[image]

[image]

**Table Schema**

```
/****** Object:  Table [jde].[F43199]    Script Date: 2/17/2020 10:53:59 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [jde].[F43199](
    [OLKCOO] [nchar](5) NULL,
    [OLDOCO] [float] NULL,
    [OLDCTO] [nchar](2) NULL,
    [OLSFXO] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [OLLNID] [float] NULL,
    [OLMCU] [nchar](12) NULL,
    [OLCO] [nchar](5) NULL,
    [OLOKCO] [nchar](5) NULL,
    [OLOORN] [nchar](8) NULL,
    [OLOCTO] [nchar](2) NULL,
    [OLOGNO] [float] NULL,
    [OLRKCO] [nchar](5) NULL,
    [OLRORN] [nchar](8) NULL,
    [OLRCTO] [nchar](2) NULL,
    [OLRLLN] [float] NULL,
    [OLDMCT] [nchar](12) NULL,
    [OLDMCS] [float] NULL,
    [OLBALU] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [OLAN8] [float] NULL,
    [OLSHAN] [float] NULL,
    [OLDRQJ] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [OLTRDJ] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [OLPDDJ] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [OLOPDJ] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [OLADDJ] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [OLCNDJ] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [OLPEFJ] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [OLPPDJ] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [OLPSDJ] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [OLDSVJ] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [OLDGL] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [OLPN] [float] NULL,
    [OLVR01] [nchar](25) NULL,
    [OLVR02] [nchar](25) NULL,
    [OLITM] [float] NULL,
    [OLLITM] [nchar](25) NULL,
    [OLAITM] [nchar](25) NULL,
    [OLLOCN] [nchar](20) NULL,
    [OLLOTN] [nchar](30) NULL,
    [OLFRGD] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [OLTHGD] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [OLFRMP] [float] NULL,
    [OLTHRP] [float] NULL,
    [OLDSC1] [nchar](30) NULL,
    [OLDSC2] [nchar](30) NULL,
    [OLLNTY] [nchar](2) NULL,
    [OLNXTR] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [OLLTTR] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [OLRLIT] [nchar](8) NULL,
    [OLPDS1] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [OLPDS2] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [OLPDS3] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [OLPDS4] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [OLPDS5] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [OLPDP1] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [OLPDP2] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [OLPDP3] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [OLPDP4] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [OLPDP5] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [OLUOM] [nchar](2) NULL,
    [OLUORG] [float] NULL,
    [OLUCHG] [float] NULL,
    [OLUOPN] [float] NULL,
    [OLUREC] [float] NULL,
    [OLCREC] [float] NULL,
    [OLURLV] [float] NULL,
    [OLOTQY] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [OLPRRC] [float] NULL,
    [OLAEXP] [float] NULL,
    [OLACHG] [float] NULL,
    [OLAOPN] [float] NULL,
    [OLAREC] [float] NULL,
    [OLARLV] [float] NULL,
    [OLFTN1] [float] NULL,
    [OLTRLV] [float] NULL,
    [OLPROV] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [OLAMC3] [float] NULL,
    [OLECST] [float] NULL,
    [OLCSTO] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [OLCSMP] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [OLINMG] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [OLASN] [nchar](8) NULL,
    [OLPRGR] [nchar](8) NULL,
    [OLCLVL] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [OLCATN] [nchar](8) NULL,
    [OLDSPR] [float] NULL,
    [OLPTC] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [OLTX] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [OLEXR1] [nchar](2) NULL,
    [OLTXA1] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [OLATXT] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [OLCNID] [nchar](20) NULL,
    [OLCDCD] [nchar](15) NULL,
    [OLNTR] [nchar](2) NULL,
    [OLFRTH] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [OLFRTC] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [OLZON] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [OLFRAT] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [OLRATT] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [OLANBY] [float] NULL,
    [OLANCR] [float] NULL,
    [OLMOT] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [OLCOT] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [OLSHCM] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [OLSHCN] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [OLUOM1] [nchar](2) NULL,
    [OLPQOR] [float] NULL,
    [OLUOM2] [nchar](2) NULL,
    [OLSQOR] [float] NULL,
    [OLUOM3] [nchar](2) NULL,
    [OLITWT] [float] NULL,
    [OLWTUM] [nchar](2) NULL,
    [OLITVL] [float] NULL,
    [OLVLUM] [nchar](2) NULL,
    [OLGLC] [nchar](4) NULL,
    [OLCTRY] [float] NULL,
    [OLFY] [float] NULL,
    [OLSTTS] [nchar](2) NULL,
    [OLRCD] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [OLFUF1] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [OLFUF2] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [OLGRWT] [float] NULL,
    [OLGWUM] [nchar](2) NULL,
    [OLLT] [nchar](2) NULL,
    [OLANI] [nchar](29) NULL,
    [OLAID] [nchar](8) NULL,
    [OLOMCU] [nchar](12) NULL,
    [OLOBJ] [nchar](6) NULL,
    [OLSUB] [nchar](8) NULL,
    [OLSBLT] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [OLSBL] [nchar](8) NULL,
    [OLASID] [nchar](25) NULL,
    [OLCCMP] [float] NULL,
    [OLTAG] [nchar](8) NULL,
    [OLWR01] [nchar](4) NULL,
    [OLPL] [nchar](4) NULL,
    [OLELEV] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [OLR001] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [OLRTNR] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [OLLCOD] [nchar](2) NULL,
    [OLPURG] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [OLPROM] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [OLFNLP] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [OLAVCH] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [OLPRPY] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [OLUNCD] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [OLMATY] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [OLRTGC] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [OLRCPF] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [OLPS01] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [OLPS02] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [OLPS03] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [OLPS04] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [OLPS05] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [OLPS06] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [OLPS07] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [OLPS08] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [OLPS09] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [OLPS10] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [OLCRMD] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [OLARTG] [nchar](12) NULL,
    [OLCORD] [float] NULL,
    [OLCHDT] [nchar](2) NULL,
    [OLDOCC] [float] NULL,
    [OLCHLN] [float] NULL,
    [OLCRCD] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [OLCRR] [float] NULL,
    [OLFRRC] [float] NULL,
    [OLFEA] [float] NULL,
    [OLFUC] [float] NULL,
    [OLFEC] [float] NULL,
    [OLFCHG] [float] NULL,
    [OLFAP] [float] NULL,
    [OLFREC] [float] NULL,
    [OLURCD] [nchar](2) NULL,
    [OLURDT] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [OLURAT] [float] NULL,
    [OLURAB] [float] NULL,
    [OLURRF] [nchar](15) NULL,
    [OLTORG] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [OLUSER] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [OLPID] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [OLJOBN] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [OLUPMJ] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [OLTDAY] [float] NULL,
    [OLVR05] [nchar](25) NULL,
    [OLVR04] [nchar](25) NULL,
    [OLSHPN] [float] NULL,
    [OLSHMT] [nchar](15) NULL,
    [OLRSHT] [float] NULL,
    [OLPRJM] [float] NULL,
    [OLDLEJ] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [OLOSFX] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [OLMERL] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [OLMCLN] [float] NULL,
    [OLMACT] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [OLKTLN] [float] NULL,
    [OLFTRL] [float] NULL,
    [OLDRQT] [float] NULL,
    [OLCTAM] [float] NULL,
    [OLCPNT] [float] NULL,
    [OLCHT] [float] NULL,
    [OLPMTN] [nchar](12) NULL,
    [OLCHRT] [float] NULL,
    [OLCHRS] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [OLCHMJ] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [OLBCRC] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [OLDUAL] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [OLUKID] [float] NOT NULL,
    [OLLDNM] [float] NULL,
    [OLMKFR] [float] NULL,
    [OLMFLG] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [OLDLNID] [float] NULL,
    [OLCMDCDE] [nchar](15) NULL,
    [OLUNSPSC] [nchar](8) NULL,
    [OLRSFX] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [OLWVID] [float] NULL,
    [OLCNTRTID] [float] NULL,
    [OLCNTRTDID] [float] NULL,
    [OLMOADJ] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [OLPODC01] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [OLPODC02] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [OLPODC03] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [OLPODC04] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [OLJBCD] [nchar](6) NULL,
    [OLSRQTY] [float] NULL,
    [OLSRUOM] [nchar](2) NULL,
    [OLCFGFL] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [OLPMPN] [nchar](30) NULL,
    [OLPNS] [float] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [F43199_PK] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [OLUKID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Please provide exact error message and some sample data.

Comment: If it's *"also float with same default precision"* (which is [53](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax)), then by definition, no.

Comment: Are you sure the column mappings are correct?

Comment: What is the destination dbms? Can you show us how you have your Destination Task configured?

Comment: The source and destination databases are both SQL Server 2018 R2